# If $f$ is compact is $f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $f$ is a compact function (image of every compact set is compact) is $f$ continuous?

**Attempt:** I can't find a counterexample. I can't prove it. I only know how to prove the converse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb Q\\
1,&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Every non-continuous function with a finite image will do —there is no need to be so extreme :-)

Comment: @Mariano: I was actually debating whether to add that comment. But I figured that this is a useful function to know anyhow.

Comment: @Mariano I liked this example, since shows that my hypotesis doesn't implies continuity at *some* point.